# Autopopulate table in javascript using underscore and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

JS noobie question..
I am trying to auto populate HTML table using jquery and underscore.  I have the following in pure js that works, but i am trying to implement this using the above mentioned libraries..

```
<table id="table"  style="border: 1px solid black;">
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var students = [
        {
            "firstname": "Woody",
            "lastname" : "Johnson",
        },
        {
            "firstname" : "Jerry",
            "lastname" : "Jones",
        },
        {
            "firstname" : "Bill",
            "lastname" : "Parcells",
        }
    ]
    for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td style="border: 1px solid black;">'+students[i].firstname+'</td></tr>';
</script>
```

Using _.each() i have tried the following code which only populate one row with the last value from my array..

```
    function fn (element, index, list) {
        $( "#table" ).html('<tr><td>'+element.firstname+'</td></tr>');
    }
    _.each(students, fn);
```

so how do i '+=' in jQuery??  tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the call to `html()` for `append()` instead, otherwise you're ostensibly overwriting the previous table entries every time a new one is added:

```
function fn (element, index, list) {
    $( "#table" ).append('<tr><td>'+element.firstname+'</td></tr>');
}
_.each(students, fn);
```

That should work!